# is there dump() function in Django / Python?

Tags: python, django

I really like PHP dump() function from Symfony, is there something equivalent in Python Django? and is there a "die()" function in Python similar with PHP?

dump() that i am talking about is

```
 https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/var_dumper.html
```

die() is:

```
http://php.net/manual/en/function.die.php
```

Comment: What do the `dump` and `die` functions do?..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If you're talking about [twig's "dump" function](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/functions/dump.html) : not natively (the closest builtin templatetag is ['debug'](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#debug) but it's a different beast) but you could very easily write your own. But with Python's debugger, interactive interpreter and logger, you probably don't need it as much as you would with PHP / Symfony.
2. Python has `sys.exit()` but you definitly **don't** want to use it in Django (nor any wsgi app) - Django apps are served as long-running processes, not as embedded scripts. If in your Django code you end up with an error case you can't handle, raise the most appropriate type of exception and let the upper layers take care of it. Note that in Python, "an error case you can't handle" is most often already an exception, so if you can't handle it, just let it propagate (eventually logging some contextual informations on the way if it makes sense).

As a more general note : don't try to write PHP in Python (nor Symfony in Django), learn to use both the language and the framework's idioms instead.